# What does Lisa call the Tibetan Buddhist Devil's name in "The Simpsons"?

Tags: the-simpsons

In an episode of *The Simpsons* I saw years ago, I remember there being a secret room below the school, Lisa discovering it and some other things I cant remember. She - being Buddhist - did though mention as she was showing the room off to certain people, the name of the Tibetan Buddhist Devil.

I never thought there was one. Or if there was, was it Mara, or the world itself, which is Maya [yes?].

I'm no scholar. What was the name of that devil Lisa mentioned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're referring to the episode [500 Keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/500_Keys) from season 22, where Lisa says:

> Get thee behind me, Namuche! That's the Buddhist Satan.

**Namuci** (sometimes transliterated as Namuche) does seem to be another name for Mara. From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rakshasa):

> In the Maha Samaya Sutta, the defeated antagonist of the Buddha, **Mara also known as Namuci or the "Dark One"** is described as a corrupted Asura whose army consisted of "Sensual passions, Discontent, Hunger and Thirst, Craving, Sloth and Drowsiness, Terror, Uncertainty, Hypocrisy and Stubbornness, Gains, Offerings, Fame and Status wrongly gained, and whoever would praise self and disparage others"

This is verified by many other sources. From the online [Chinese Buddhism Encyclopedia](http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/index.php/Mara):

> **Mara**: In theistic religions the Devil, sometimes also known as Satan or Beelzebub, is a being completely opposed to God and to goodness. [...] Mara is sometimes also called Kaõha, the Dark One (Majjhima Nikaya 1. 377), or **Namuci** (Digha Nikaya 2. 259).

Comment: Thank you kind sir, this is spot on. I was almost a "buddhist" myself at one point stealing incence and books from a temple.. Sorry Lama. But I never even knew he had a name like this. Do you remember seeing it or did you google the entire bit? (and not [just] the bit about wiki./

Comment: I saw it but didn't remember what she said exactly. I looked up that part.

Comment: how do you pronounce the name? Nah Mooh Chi?

Comment: Yes, though I think Lisa pronounced it as -cheh or -chey.

Comment: Did you know God is the [only](https://twitter.com/qikipedia/status/907438619626897408) character in The Simpsons to have five fingers?